# Find maximum gap between elements of an array

Tags: python, array, interview-questions

I am solving interview questions from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/max-distance/).

> **Problem** : Given an array A of integers, find the maximum of j - i subjected to the constraint of A[i] <= A[j].
>
> Example : A =  [3 5 4 2]  Output : 2 for the pair (3, 4)

Here is my solution:

```
def maximum_gap( A):
    """find maximum gap between index(j -i ) with  A[i] <= A[j]"""
    gap = 0
    A = list(map( list,enumerate(A))) # get list of [index,value]
    for item in A:
        item[0],item[1] = item[1], item[0] # swap index with value
    a = sorted(A)  # sort list A as per values

    max_index = a[0][1] # initialise max_index to first index in sorted list
    min_index = a[0][1] # initialise min_index to first index in sorted list

    for v,i in a:
        if i > max_index:  # if current > max_index, set max to current
            max_index = i
        if i < min_index:  # if current < min_index, set min to current
            min_index = i
            max_index = i  # reset max to current
        
        gap_new = max_index - min_index  # find the maximum gap
        if gap < gap_new:
            gap = gap_new
            
    return gap
```

Test cases:

```
print maximum_gap([-1,-1,2])  == 2
print maximum_gap([1,3,5,7,2,4,10])  ==  6
print maximum_gap([3,2,1]) == 0
print maximum_gap([3,2,1,4]) == 3
print maximum_gap([2,2,1,4,3])  == 4
print maximum_gap([ 0,1,2,3])  == 3
print maximum_gap([ 100,100,100,100,100])  == 4
```

How can I make this code better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) notes that you can pass [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) as the second argument to get a running minimum. So the maximum gap can be computed like this:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def maximum_gap(A):
    "Return maximum j-i subject to A[i] <= A[j]."
    B = sorted(range(len(A)), key=A.__getitem__)
    return max(j - i for i, j in zip(accumulate(B, min), B))
```

As for the test cases, this kind of problem is suitable for [random testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_testing). That's because it's straightforward to write a [test oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_oracle), a function solving the problem that is clearly correct (but inefficient). Here we could write:

```
from itertools import product

def maximum_gap_slow(A):
    "Return maximum j-i subject to A[i] <= A[j]."
    return max(j - i for i, j in product(range(len(A)), repeat=2) if A[i] <= A[j])
```

Then we can generate random test cases and use the test oracle to check the result, for example using the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module:

```
from random import randrange
from unittest import TestCase

class TestMaximumGap(TestCase):
    def test_random(self):
        for n in range(1, 100):
            A = [randrange(n) for _ in range(n)]
            self.assertEqual(maximum_gap(A), maximum_gap_slow(A), A)
```

Comment: Thanks for the review. I am using Python 2.7 so i think i cant use itertools.accumulate but i will keep a note of it. Secondly i wanted to ask how does " B = sorted(range(len(A)), key=A.__getitem__)" works?

Comment: @LatikaAgarwal: (1) The documentation for `itertools.accumulate` has a recipe for implementing it that ought to work in Python 2.7. (2) It would be a good exercise to try to figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

The code looks pretty good. Here are a few suggestions to make it more Pythonic.

#### Use generator expressions to their fullest

The entirety of the initialization of `a` can be reduced from:

```
A = list(map(list, enumerate(A)))  # get list of [index,value]
for item in A:
    item[0], item[1] = item[1], item[0]  # swap index with value
a = sorted(A)  # sort list A as per values

for v, i in a:
    ....
```

To:

```
for v, i in sorted((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(A)):
    ....
```

#### Use Python's builtins:

Python has the `max()` function that will replace

```
gap_new = max_index - min_index  # find the maximum gap
if gap < gap_new:
    gap = gap_new
```

with:

```
gap = max(gap, max_index - min_index)
```

similarly:

```
if i > max_index:  # if current > max_index, set max to current
    max_index = i
```

can be just:

```
max_index = max(max_index, i)
```

#### pep8

The violations were very minor, by I recommend formatting your code in accordance 
with [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  This is important 
when sharing code, as the consistent style makes it much easier for other 
programmers to read your code.  There are various tools available to 
assist in making the code pep8 compliant.  I use the 
[PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE which will show pep8 
violations right in the editor.

#### Restructured Code:

```
def maximum_gap(A):
    """find maximum gap between index(j -i ) with  A[i] <= A[j]"""

    min_index = max_index = len(A)
    gap = 0

    for v, i in sorted((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(A)):
        if i < min_index:  # if current < min, set min & max to current
            min_index = max_index = i
        else:
            # if current > max, set max to current
            max_index = max(max_index, i)

        # find the maximum gap
        gap = max(gap, max_index - min_index)

    return gap


assert maximum_gap([-1, -1, 2]) == 2
assert maximum_gap([1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 10]) == 6
assert maximum_gap([3, 2, 1]) == 0
assert maximum_gap([3, 2, 1, 4]) == 3
assert maximum_gap([2, 2, 1, 4, 3]) == 4
assert maximum_gap([0, 1, 2, 3]) == 3
assert maximum_gap([100, 100, 100, 100, 100]) == 4
```